# Regression coefficients and abline in R - linear regression

Tags: r, plot, dataset, linear-regression

Thanks in advance for your attention. Here it's my problem:

I have a dataframe, this is it's structure (I have deleted some rows):

```
DATE        CASES
02/01/2013    1
02/01/2013    2
03/01/2013    3
04/01/2013    4
04/01/2013    5
08/01/2013    6
08/01/2013    7
16/01/2013    8
18/01/2013    9
18/01/2013    10
18/01/2013    11
21/01/2013    12
22/01/2013    13
23/01/2013    14
23/01/2013    15
23/01/2013    16
23/01/2013    17
23/01/2013    18
23/01/2013    19
24/01/2013    20
24/01/2013    21
24/01/2013    22
30/01/2013    23
30/01/2013    24
```

And this is what I do:

```
d<-read.csv("...",sep=";")
model<-lm(d$CASES~d$DATE)
plot(sort(d[,1]),d[,2])
abline(model)
```

After the last command I've got this message:

```
abline: only using the first two of 11 regression coefficients
```

It works "fine" with a small dataset but it does not make any sense if I work with the whole dataset.

This is the plot I get (using the complete dataset): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YL3O.jpg

If you want to try, this is the complete one:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qrd9lt4r7gs1r98/regresion.csv

I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong because I have no idea. Does abline work fine?

Thank you again!

Comment: Your dates are read in as factors. You need to convert them to `Date`s or numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DATE` variable is a `factor` (or possibly a `character`). You need to recode it to `numeric` - but be careful to do this right and not get the internal `factor` coding, so recode first as `Date`, then as `numeric`.

Read the data:

```
d <- read.csv("regresion.csv",sep=";")
```

Convert your dates (which were interpreted as unstructured strings and automatically converted to `factor`s by `read.csv()`):

```
d$FECHA <- as.Date(d$FECHA,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

For regression, convert these to `numeric`:

```
date.num <- as.numeric(d$FECHA)
date.num
```

Run the regression:

```
model <- lm(d$ALERTAS.EUROPA~date.num)
```

Plot - note that for the plot to make sense, we again need the x axis (`FECHA`) to be a `Date`, which is why we converted it above:

```
plot(d$FECHA,d$ALERTAS.EUROPA)
```

Finally, add the regression line:

```
abline(model,col="red",lwd=2)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Now it does make sense, but I can't see the abline. Do I have to do anything else? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer. Better now?